# Can we have tags for "Report Builder" and "Reporting Services"?

Tags: feature-request

I have posted [a question about SQL Server, its Management Studio and its Report builder](https://superuser.com/questions/1325611/i-get-rsprocessingaborted-and-rserrorexecutingcommand-randomly-in-my-sql-ser) in Super User a few minutes ago and provided that Super User is the right board for that question, [which obviously isn't so obvious concerning that topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106066/where-should-ssrs-report-builder-questions-be-asked), I have a request:

Can we have tags for the Reporting Services and the Report Builder? Because I wanted to add at least place a tag for the report builder in my aforementioned question. [Server Fault has a tag for the services](https://serverfault.com/questions/221034/sql-server-report-builder-from-citrix), [Database Administrators has tags for both the services and the builder](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/report-builder), and even Stackoverflow, which is the place I would see completely unfit for SQL Server Report Builder questions, [has a tag for the Report Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359945/ssrs-fails-to-run-on-remote-server-but-runs-fine-locally) (plus a much more shinier sql-server tag).

Also I would suggest that the tag for the Report Builder should not just be "Report Builder", because that is quite ambigious in my opinion, but rather with its complete and correct name "SQL Server Report Builder".

Comment: As you noted, it's very ambiguous.  Even [sql-server-report-builder] is ambiguous if there is, or could be, more than one, even if the names aren't alike (one = name, one = generic description).  Getting too granular doesn't really add value as much as tag bloat.  The first criterion would be, are the experts in Report Builder" or "Reporting Services" a substantively different group from our experts in SQL Server?  You don't need to ask your question in the tags.

Answer (score 4):

> Can we have tags for the Reporting Services and the Report Builder?

If SO has 20,000 questions tagged as [reporting- services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting-services) why are you asking it on Superuser which has none?  [Where should SSRS/Report Builder questions be asked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106066/where-should-ssrs-report-builder-questions-be-asked) indicates SO is the correct community.

However, your question is more about SSMS and/or  SQL Server Report Builder than reporting services in general.  I personally feel that these tags are extremely ambiguous and should not be created.  Your question being tagged with those specific tags, would NOT make them easier to find, so using those tags wouldn't improve your question in the slightest.

Comment: Worth pointing out.  You are using PostgreSQL but tagged it was SQL Server 2012.  Which means your use of tags seems ambiguous and/or arbitrary

Comment: In my question it was stated "However the views themself use functions and also gather information via OPENQUERY from a linked PostgreSQL server." Again, "ALSO", they are not exclusively accessing PostgreSQL tables. And even if, the Postgre queries are executed via OPENQUERY on the SQL Server with the help of SQL Server Management Studio. SQL Server is the main act here, not Postgre SQL.

Comment: There is a difference between SQL Server (any) and SQL Server 2012 (MSSQL).  You made no mention of MSSQL Server 2012 in the question (except you used the tag)